# Powershell refer to objects in table

Tags: select, powershell, group-by

I have a script I am working on that will output all fileNames and lineNumbers of a key word search.

```
$Paths = gci . *.* -rec | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | resolve-path
foreach($path in $Paths)
{
    $ftp += Select-String -Path $Path -Pattern "FTP"
}
$ftpgroups = $ftp | select fileName,LineNumber | Format-Table -groupBy Filename
```

I decided to go with ft -groupby because group-object was not working correctly. But I need a way to reference this table so I can put it into a csv. When using the get-member commandlet it only gives me properties of formating. The ideal output for this is to have 1 fileName matched up to a group of fileLines. That way I can match that up to the path (which group-object worked succesfully on).
I am open to new ideas if I am going about this the wrong way. Thank you in advanced, hope it doesn't cause you as much trouble as it has me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found, the output of any of the `Format-*` cmdlets is formatting objects.  These objects are meant for display to the console and not further manipulation. You really need `Group-Object` for this. In what way wasn't it working for you?  I would think, this would work:

```
$ftpgroups = $ftp | Select Filename,LineNumber | Group Filename
```

Comment: Then after grouping use `Export-Csv`.

Comment: Awesome. This worked great for me thank you. I believe it wasn't working correctly because i was trying to group it first. 
`$ftpgroups = $ftp | Group Filename | select Filename,LineNumber` doesn't work. Appreciate your help.